# Getopt not reading all options

Tags: python, command-line, getopt

this is my first time using Getopt in python and I came across a problem:

```
opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "hrs", ["help","random","somethingelse"])

for o, a in opts:
    if o in "-h" or "--help":
        help()
    elif o in "-r" or "--random":
        random()
    elif o in "-s" or "--somethingelse":
        somethingelse()
```

If I were to type: python test.py -r or python test.py -s. It would still go to the help function instead of going to the random() or somethingelse() function.

Comment: Your conditions are not correct perhaps you meant: `if o in ['-h', '--help']:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the possible options in lists or tuples:

```
opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "hrs", ["help","random","somethingelse"])

for o, a in opts:
    if o in ["-h", "--help"]:
        help()
    elif o in ["-r", "--random"]:
        random()
    elif o in ["-s", "--somethingelse"]:
        somethingelse()
```

The way you currently have it, your first condition `if o in "-h" or "--help":` is perfectly valid Python, but it will always be `True`, because what you are actually testing is the "truthiness" of `o in "-h"` and `"--help"` respectively. This is always `True` because even if `o in "-h"` is `False`, `"--help"` is always `True` since it is a non-empty string.

On the other hand, if you test `if o in ["-h", "--help"]:`, this will check if `o` is one of the items in the list `["-h", "--help"]`, and will only return `True` if it is.